# Pandas Combine Multiple CSV's and Output as One Large File

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So I currently have a directory, we'll call it */mydir*, that contains 36 CSV files, each 2.1 GB and with the same dimensions. They are all the same size, and I want to read them into pandas, concatenate them together side-by-side (so the amount of rows stays the same), and then output the resulting dataframe as one large csv. The code I have for this works for combining a few of them but reaches a memory error after a certain point. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this than what I have.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir('/mydir'):
    df.concat([df, pd.read_csv('/mydir' + file, dtype = 'float)], axis = 1)
df.to_csv('mydir/file.csv')
```

It was suggested to me to break it up into smaller pieces, combine the files in groups of 6, then combine these together in turn but I don't know if this is a valid solution that will avoid the memory error problem

EDIT: view of the directory:

```
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:35 2010.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:32 2001.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:28 1983.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:21 2009.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:21 1991.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:07 2000.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:06 1982.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:01 1990.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 10:01 2008.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 09:55 1999.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 09:54 1981.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 09:42 2007.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 09:42 1998.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 09:42 1989.csv
-rw-rw---- 1 m2762 2.1G Jul 11 09:42 1980.csv
```

Comment: do all files have the same # of rows?

Comment: Yes, the dimensions of all of them are identical, I'll update the post to specify that.

Comment: what about using Linux `paste` utility - `paste -d',' *.csv > result.csv`?

Comment: Well it's currently running but that does seem promising. Is there a way to sort the files in the directory? Each one is a year of data and ideally I want them to be in chronological order which they currently are not.

Comment: can you post an output of `ls /mydir/*.csv` ?

Comment: what are you going to do with this 72 GB csv when you are done with it? maybe a database file (or h5 file) + blaze would be a better target... alternately, do you need _all_ the columns in each file? you may be able to reduce your memory footprint by selecting only a few columns...

Comment: @MaxU I edited to include the output. Ideally the first file would be 1980.csv then 1981.csv etc... Would simply moving them to a new folder in the right order work?

Comment: @Corley, I'll be running a dimensionality reduction on the data to get it down to a more manageable size for further analysis. I could potentially throw out rows but at this point I want to keep all the columns

Comment: @JSolomonCulp, i guess `paste -d, *.csv > result.csv` should do the trick (in the right order)

Comment: And i would definitely pay attention at @CorleyBrigman's comment. I'd convert such a huge CSV into HDF5 file - it's much more reliable, faster, keeps data types, supports compression and gives you a possibility to read it conditionally...

Comment: I'll have a look at HDF5. How hard is it to convert to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Chunk Them All!

```
from glob import glob
import os

# grab files
files = glob('./[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv')

# simplify the file reading
# notice this will create a generator
# that goes through chunks of the file
# at a time
def read_csv(f, n=100):
    return pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0, chunksize=n)

# simplify the concatenation
def concat(lot):
    return pd.concat(lot, axis=1)

# simplify the writing
# make sure mode is append and header is off
# if file already exists
def to_csv(f, df):
    if os.path.exists(f):
        mode = 'a'
        header = False
    else:
        mode = 'w'
        header = True
    df.to_csv(f, mode=mode, header=header)

# Fun stuff! zip will take the next element of the generator
# for each generator created for each file
# concat one chunk at a time and write
for lot in zip(*[read_csv(f, n=10) for f in files]):
    to_csv('out.csv', concat(lot))
```

Comment: That seems to have done it. Never used glob before but it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the answer to MaxU is that all the files have the same number of rows, and assuming further that minor CSV differences like quoting are done the same way in all the files, you don't need to do this with Pandas.  Regular file `readlines` will give you the strings that you can concatenate and write out.  Assuming further that you can supply the number of rows.  Something like this code:

```
    numrows = 999 # whatever.  Probably pass as argument to function or on cmdline
    out_file = open('myout.csv','w')
    infile_names = [ 'file01.csv',
                     'file02.csv',
                      ..
                     'file36.csv' ]

    # open all the input files
    infiles = []
    for fname in infile_names:
        infiles.append(open(fname))

    for i in range(numrows):
        # read a line from each input file and add it to the output string
        out_csv=''
        for infile2read in infiles:
            out_csv += infile2read.readline().strip() + ','
        out_csv[-1] = '\n' # replace final comma with newline

        # write this rows data out to the output file
        outfile.write(out_csv)

    #close the files
    for f in infiles:
        f.close()
    outfile.close()
```